# Dialog not centered on window height, but on document height instead

Tags: jquery, html, css, primefaces, dialog

Using primefaces 6.2 now, I experienced this issue already when using 6.0 so I thought it was time to investigate. When the content height of the page (the document) is larger then the window (the viewport of the browser), then you can clearly see that instead of centering on the window, the dialog is centered on the document. When having very large pages, the dialog is still centered on the page level, and not on the window level. It means that if the page is at least twice as high as the window, the dialog falls of the window. To test this i made a sample page:

```
<html lang="nl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="show">
        <p:commandButton value="Test" onclick="PF('dialog').show();" />
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="dialog" widgetVar="dialog" modal="true" height="100">

        <h:form id="refresh">
            <p:button onclick="document.location.href = document.location.href;" value="Refresh" />
        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>

    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>

</h:body>
</html>
```

In this sample page, it will trigger the dialog. When using on most laptops, it will show dialog nicely in the center because the screen resolution is big enough. Now, resize the browser screen untill a scrollbar appears. It means some 'test' lines should fall off the window. Now trigger again the dialog. In my case it is not centered anymore. Resizing the browsers has also no effect...

The odd thing is, when testing this on the Primefaces showcase, and resizing the screen, the dialog is always centered! Conclusion is there is something different, but I only use base configuration for primefaces. I noticed though that everything is wrapped in layout container on the primefaces site. Also tried to wrap everything in a layout container, but it doesn't help.

Anybody has an idea why this happens. Is this a bug I should report? Is this as designed, and the dialog will ALWAYS center on the document (and for a strange reason the showcase doesn't follow this logic...).

Comment: I would try and create a reprodcible test case using the small PrimeFaces Test project and submit it as a defect if you can reproduce it. The Test project is here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: a doctype declaration needs to be added: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Although the declaration is not mandatory with XHTML5 documents; for using primefaces it is mandatory in fact. If not, some components may have unexpected behavior, like this dialog.

More info: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4115